# Do Arduino Nano Every devices short out?

Tags: arduino-nano

I have an Arduino Nano Every device that seems to have shorted out.

I use a lighted USB hub with buttons that turn connections on and off.  Each button has its own LED that indicates power state for its associated port.

Anyway, when I plug my Arduino Nano Every into that USB hub, the lighted buttons turn off for half of the hub, like the Arduino is shorting out the hub.

I use a different Arduino and have no problems, so it's definitely the Arduino.

Any idea what could have caused this?  I was using the Arduino with a TMUX1511 switch chip and using pins  D9-D12 to turn on and off the 4 internal switches in the chip.  It's using very low voltage (5v) and amperage is (25 mA).  I used the 5v and gnd pins on the Arduino to power the TMUX1511 chip, but with such low amperage, I can't see how that could have caused the Arduino to fry.

Any ideas?

Comment: Probably you at some time created a short somewhere. Though that is impossible to say for us. We don't see the board and we don't know your exact circuit, that you used. Have you tested the Arduino with a different power source? If yes, was it working there?

Comment: I have 5 identical devices that use these Arduino Nano Everys.  Only one has had this problem and it is after it was connected for several weeks.  One day, it just stopped working and when I checked it out, it appeared that the Arduino Nano Every was malfunctioning.  I replaced the Every, and now the defective device works fine.

Comment: Still the same answer. You are right that the TMUX chip shouldnt have fried the Arduino. So I can only guess, that something else happened, for example a short, maybe only for a short time. But how should someone find out, what exactly happened? Imagine I would ask you "My car doesn't turn on anymore. I just drove the normal way home. As I drove the way with another car, it worked, so its definitely the car, which has problems. What could have happened?" There are many possible answers to that question. Without information on what exactly happened when the error occurred, nobody can say.

Comment: Is there anything connected to the MUX, which you didn't mention?

Comment: Just using the Arduino to switch the MUX back and forth between sources.  The MUX is connecting and disconnecting network wires.  Just turning on and off network connectivity, so no major voltage or amperage that would cause the Every to fry...  Maybe I just got a defective one.  I've never had problems with them before.  I guess we'll see on the other 5 devices that I'm using, but they've been fine for the past month with no issues.

Answer (score 1):

this might because of powering issue...try using different source having a good number of current capability. likely up